# UWP background task location tracking

Tags: background, uwp, location

I'm trying to develop an UWP app that is able to continually track the user's location in an in-process background task. I've been looking at the Microsoft sample code on GitHub (geolocation / Secenario3_BackgroundTask) but the problem there is that it is based on a TimeTrigger. The shortest interval that TimeTrigger allows is 15 minutes, but I need to get location updates much more frequently. Let's say at least once per minute. Is that possible at all?

I've seen that there is a LocationTrigger but there's not much documentation for it. I don't understand when this trigger gets fired. In my tests, it never got fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationTrigger` is used for [Geofencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence), it is triggered when a mobile device enters or leaves a particular area.

As you say, `TimeTrigger` is not good for your requirement because it has an interval of 15 minutes at the minimum.

Windows 10 introduces a new mechanism called [extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution). Location tracking is one of the supported scenarios in which you ask the OS to keep your app running when another app is switched to the foreground.

This is a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cs/Scenario3_LocationTrackingReason.xaml.cs) for your.

Comment: One additional thing: now after pretty exactly 24 hours of running it in the background I got a `ExtendedExecutionRevokedReason.SystemPolicy` callback. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: This is expected, system can revoke the session _at any point_. From doc: `SystemPolicy`:  Background execution is revoked due to system resources. Pay attention to system resources like memory usage, and battery. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) has some more info.