# How Do I Get Real-Time Location Updates in UWP when my App is in the Background?

Tags: c#, uwp, background, geolocation, xamarin.uwp

A project I am working on for my job supports location tracking, and we recently made the decision to add support for location tracking while our application is in the background. We support for the following platforms: iOS, Android, and UWP. As the title implies, I am seeking help implementing this feature on UWP (both desktop and phone). I was wondering if anyone could either help me out or point me to some code for someone who's written a GPS/run tracking app for UWP.

I have experimented with both Extended Execution Sessions and Background Task. In fact, I am currently using both in my app right now, and neither have had much luck in getting background tracking to work on UWP. The location service we are using is custom code based on the [MvvmCross UWP Location Watcher](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Plugins/Location/Platforms/Uap/MvxWCommonLocationWatcher.cs). For reference, some excerpts from the project `App.xaml.cs`:

```
// This method is associated with the LeavingBackground event
private async void WillEnterForeground(object sender, LeavingBackgroundEventArgs e)
{
        if (_trackingNotificationTask == null)
        {
            await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            RegisterTrackingNotificationTask();
        }

        if (_backgroundTrackingSession == null)
        {
            using (var backgroundSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession())
            {
                backgroundSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking;
                backgroundSession.Description = "Track Responder Location in Background";
                backgroundSession.Revoked += OnSessionRevoked;

                var result = await backgroundSession.RequestExtensionAsync();

                switch (result)
                {
                    case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:
                        _backgroundTrackingSession = backgroundSession;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        var locationService = Mvx.Resolve<ILocationService>();
        locationService?.Resume();

        if (_appInBackground)
        {
            ClearAllNotifications();

            if (_backgroundTrackingTask != null)
            {
                _backgroundTrackingTask.Unregister(true);
                _backgroundTrackingTask = null;
            }

            await Mvx.Resolve<IEventInformationSyncService>().SyncUserSetting();
            await Mvx.Resolve<IAppService>().IsMobileStatusGood();
            _appInBackground = false;
        }
}

// This Method is associated with the EnteredBackground event
private void DidEnterBackground(object sender, EnteredBackgroundEventArgs e)
{
        var deferral = e.GetDeferral();

        // Request permission for background tracking
        RegisterBackgroundTrackingTask();

        var appSettingService = Mvx.Resolve<IAppSettingService>();

        if (!NeedToUpgradeWindows() && Core.App.IsResponderTrackingEnabled()) // Are we in an event and is responder tracking enabled?
        {
            ShowNotification();
        }

        _appInBackground = true;

        deferral.Complete();
}

private void RegisterBackgroundTrackingTask()
{
        if (NeedToUpgradeWindows())
        {
            if (!_shownUpgradeMessage)
            {
                Mvx.Resolve<IUserInteraction>().Alert("Your current windows version does not support background tasks. Please upgrade to windows version 1709 or above to utilize background tasks.", () => { _shownUpgradeMessage = true; });
            }
            return;
        }
        var backgroundTrackingBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
        {
            Name = BackgroundTrackingTask.Name,
            TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundTrackingTask).FullName,
            IsNetworkRequested = true
        };

        backgroundTrackingBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
        _backgroundTrackingTask = backgroundTrackingBuilder.Register();

        _backgroundTrackingTask.Completed += OnBackgroundTrackingTaskCompleted;


}

private void RegisterTrackingNotificationTask()
{
        if (NeedToUpgradeWindows())
        {
            if (!_shownUpgradeMessage)
            {
                Mvx.Resolve<IUserInteraction>().Alert("Your current windows version does not support background tasks. Please upgrade to windows version 1709 or above to utilize background tasks.", () => { _shownUpgradeMessage = true; });
            }
            return;
        }
        if (IsTaskRegistered(TrackingNotificationHandlerTask.Name))
        {
            return;
        }
        var notificationTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
        {
            Name = TrackingNotificationHandlerTask.Name,
            TaskEntryPoint = typeof(TrackingNotificationHandlerTask).FullName
        };

        notificationTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());
        _trackingNotificationTask = notificationTaskBuilder.Register();

        _trackingNotificationTask.Completed += OnNotificationActivated;
}

private void OnBackgroundTrackingTaskCompleted(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
        var settingValues = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;

        var success = (bool)settingValues["Success"];

        if (success)
        {
            var locationService = Mvx.Resolve<ILocationService>();

            var location = new MvxGeoLocation
            {
                Coordinates = new MvxCoordinates
                {
                    Latitude = (double)settingValues["Latitude"],
                    Longitude = (double)settingValues["Longitude"],
                    Accuracy = (double)settingValues["Accuracy"]
                },
                Timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Parse((string)settingValues["Time"]))
            };

            locationService.OnLocation(location, true);
        }
}

private void OnNotificationActivated(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
        var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var action = (string)settings.Values["NotificationAction"];

        var locationService = Mvx.Resolve<ILocationService>();

        switch (action)
        {
            case "pause":
                locationService?.ClearResponderTrackingOptions();
                break;
            case "resume":
                locationService?.RecycleResponderTracking();
                break;
        }

        ClearAllNotifications();
        ShowNotification();
}
```

Thank you all very much in advance. Please let me know if you guys need anything else!

Comment: Derive from [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733355/7254781), the better way to get current location info in real time is using [`Extended Execution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution). and location tracking is supported session. I could not figure out the issue with your code, it looks correct. please check this [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx) that descript detail about usage scenario of `Extended Execution`.